# Possible solutions of this problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given that N is a natural number .Then I was trying to find the number of positive integral solutions of the equation 
>   $$1!+2!+3!+4!+.....+x!=N^2$$

By hit and trial, $1$ and $3$ are obvious solutions for $x$. 
**But are these the only solutions and how can I find any other solutions if present ?**

Answer (score 3):

If $x\ge 4$, then $$1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+\cdots+x!\equiv $$

$$\equiv 1!+2!+3!+4!=33\equiv 3\pmod{5},$$

but $3$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $5$ because, e.g., you can notice that if $k\in\mathbb Z$, then $(5k\pm 2)^2\equiv (\pm 2)^2\equiv 4\pmod{5}$, $(5k\pm 1)^2\equiv (\pm 1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, $(5k)^2\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, so $0,1,4$ are all the quadratic residues mod $5$. Therefore $x\le 3$ and $x=1$, $x=3$ give the only solutions.

Comment: What is a quadratic residue modulo ?